# This batch code is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, blue-screen-of-death

Fake blue screen is not working:

Everything after echo os the text even '***'

---

```
@echo off 
mode con: cols=160 lines=180
color 1f 
echo ***STOP: 0x000000D 1 (0x00000000, 0xF73120AE, 0xC0000008, 0xC0000000 
echo. 
echo A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage 
echo to your computer
echo. 
echo DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL 
echo. 
echo If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your 
echo computer. If thi screen appears again, follow these steps: 
echo. 
echo Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed. If this is a 
echo new installation, ask your hardware or software manifacturer for any Windows updates 
echo you might need. 
echo. 
echo If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware or software. 
echo Disable BIOS memory options such  as cachsing or shadowing. If you need  to use Safe 
echo Mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer, press f8 to select 
echo Advanced Startup Options, and then select Safe Mode. 
echo.
echo *** WXYZ.SYS - Adress F73120AE base at C00000000, DateStamp 36b07a3 
echo. 
echo. 
echo Kernel Debugger Using: COM2 (Port 0x2f8, Baud Rate 19200> 
echo Beginning dump of phisical memory 
echo Physical memory dump complete.  Contact your system administrator or 
echo technical support group. 
Pause 
echo.
```

---

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Please provide your current output and the desired output so we can help you (at least clarify what are you looking for)

Comment: owkay Cristian Ramon-Cortes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `>` on this line

```
echo Kernel Debugger Using: COM2 (Port 0x2f8, Baud Rate 19200>
```

It is recognized as redirection operator to write output to a file.